# What are the advantages of Ox-rich staged combustion?

Tags: propulsion, engine-design, engines, oxidizer, combustion

In the context of staged combustion, I understand that burning ox-rich creates complications associated with having hot, high pressure, oxidizer. Some engines, notably the RD-170 and RD-180 family run ox-rich. The [wikipedia page for the RD-180](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-180#Design_and_specifications) explains this by saying:

> The engine runs with an oxidizer-to-fuel ratio of 2.72 and employs an oxygen-rich preburner, unlike typical fuel-rich US designs. The 
>   thermodynamics of the cycle allow an oxygen-rich preburner to give a greater **power-to-weight ratio**, but with the drawback that high-pressure, high-temperature gaseous oxygen must be transported throughout the engine.

However this block isn't cited and I haven't been able to find much in the way of corroborating sources. I have however found some [message boards](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=18646.msg674763#msg674763) that mention **soot buildup** offhand, but again, not a lot of further reading that I can find.

Can someone provide a conclusive answer on either the soot buildup, an **explanation of where a power-to-weight ratio advantage comes from**, or some combination of the two?

Comment: I note that LOX is ~70% denser than kerosene, so you'd get more mass flow through smaller/lighter pipes going ox-rich. The gaseous expansion characteristics would be different as well but I don't know how that plays out.

Comment: oh that's an interesting take. I'd been thinking about how the density comparison might play out but never thought about pipe weights.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably a small thing compared to the factors Organic Marble covers in his answer, though.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Higher density working fluids lead to less work potential in turbines. Higher density is a con here. The coking is the big issue with fuel-rich preburners.

Oxygen rich isn't particularly Russian rockets. The Russians just do staged combustion with everything, the west just does it with O2/H2.

Comment: hey @everyday-astronaut I recently watched your raptor video (for at least the 3rd time) wherein you mention coking as one of the primary factors for methalox selection. Out of curiosity was this post a source for that project or did you find other sources?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the super-detailed and very informative [NASA-CR 165404 Fuel/Oxidizer-Rich High-Pressure Preburners](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19820002372), the primary advantages of hydrocarbon-fueled oxidizer-rich staged-combustion engines is that "carbon formation, coking, and the attainment of ignition are no longer issues." (page 133)

This useful rocket engine cycle overview [presentation](https://archive.org/download/engine-cycles-2/EngineCycles-2.pdf) from Purdue University's AAE 539: Advanced Rocket Propulsion class mentions only the carbon formation (sooting) issue as an advantage (pdf page 17).

The book "Progress In Astronautics and Aeronautics: Liquid Rocket Thrust Chambers", excerpted at Google Books [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0HWotm1k40QC&pg=PA632&lpg=PA632&dq=comparison%20of%20fuel-rich%20and%20oxidizer-rich%20staged%20combustion%20engines&source=bl&ots=MXD1VbdCyt&sig=ojQTzyVnwnz5b2eToQUhsU0AQio&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUjqrh-ZXWAhXnqlQKHZXwBcg4ChDoAQg_MAQ#v=onepage&q=comparison%20of%20fuel-rich%20and%20oxidizer-rich%20staged%20combustion%20engines&f=false), may provide a clue as to the claimed power-to-weight advantage.  It shows an analysis that concludes for equal turbine temperatures and pump discharge pressures, an oxidizer-rich cycle has an 87% increase in chamber pressure over a fuel-rich cycle.  This would seem to imply that a smaller oxidizer-rich engine could produce the same thrust as a larger fuel-rich engine.  Unfortunately, the book is only excerpted there, and I don't own a copy.